# Scale blocks relative to the side

Tags: html, css

How to make the blocks increase not from the center, but from the edge that blocks 1 2 should increase to the right side and 3 4 to the left side.

```css
div#fotoContainer div#zoomFoto {

    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    transition: transform .2s;
    width: 40%;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 150%;
      float: right;
border: 1px solid black;

}

div#fotoContainer div#zoomFoto:hover {

    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);

}
```

```html
<div id="fotoContainer">
<div id="zoomFoto"><figure>3</figure></div><!--
--><div id="zoomFoto"><figure>1</figure></div>




<div id="zoomFoto"><figure>4</figure></div><!--
--><div id="zoomFoto"><figure>2</figure></div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use  `transform-origin` property**

**note:**
**Id is unique selector.. use class as a `.zoomFoto`..**

see [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)

```css
div#fotoContainer div.zoomFoto {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    transition: transform .2s;
    width: 40%;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 150%;
     float: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div#fotoContainer div.zoomFoto:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transform-origin: right;
}
div#fotoContainer div.zoomFoto:nth-child(2n+2):hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="fotoContainer">
<div class="zoomFoto right"><figure>3</figure></div>
<div class="zoomFoto right"><figure>1</figure></div>
<div class="zoomFoto left"><figure>4</figure></div>
<div class="zoomFoto left"><figure>2</figure></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the property `transform-origin`.

```css
div#fotoContainer div#zoomFoto {

    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    transition: transform .2s;
    width: 40%;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 150%;
      float: right;
border: 1px solid black;

}

div#fotoContainer div#zoomFoto:hover {

    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);

}

.left-box {
  transform-origin: center right;
}

.right-box {
  transform-origin: center left;
}
```

```html
<div id="fotoContainer">
<div id="zoomFoto" class="right-box"><figure>3</figure></div><!--
--><div id="zoomFoto" class="left-box"><figure>1</figure></div>




<div id="zoomFoto" class="right-box"><figure>4</figure></div><!--
--><div id="zoomFoto" class="left-box"><figure>2</figure></div>



</div>
```